# How do I start a group call on Azure Communication Services with the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-communication-services

I am trying to implement group calling using Azure Communication Services, using only `azure-communication-calling` which provides the `CallClient`. When I access the group Id from `Call`, that is returned after `CallClient.startCall`, through `Call.info.groupId` it's blank.
My question is, how do I get the group Id so that other users can join. Or is there a way to call `CallClient.startCall` that initiates the call as a group call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I get the group Id so that other users can join. Or is there a way to call CallClient.startCall that initiates the call as a group call?

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/how-tos/calling-sdk/manage-calls?pivots=platform-web#join-a-group-call):

> The `groupId` parameter requires data to be in **GUID** format. We recommend using **randomly generated GUIDs** that aren't considered personal data in your systems.

To start a new group call or join an ongoing group call, use the join method and pass an object with a `groupId`.

```
const context = { groupId: '<GUID>'};
const call = callAgent.join(context);
```

To generate `GUID`, you can refer to [How to create a GUID / UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid)

**Updated references**: [CallInfo interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-communication-services/@azure/communication-calling/callinfo?view=azure-communication-services-js),  [Call Automation overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-automation-apis), [Learn Azure Communication Services](https://www.thoughtstuff.co.uk/learn-azure-communication-services) and [Learn Azure Communication Services Day 7 – Joining a Group Call](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2021/03/learn-azure-communication-services-day-7-joining-a-group-call/)

Comment: Thank you. This was very useful. I found [this blog series](https://www.thoughtstuff.co.uk/learn-azure-communication-services) which explains this concept further, especially [this post](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2021/03/learn-azure-communication-services-day-7-joining-a-group-call/).